# How to prevent svg drag on specific element?

Tags: mouseevent, draggable, svgpanzoom

I'm using the fantastic svg-pan-zoom plugin (https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) to pan/zoom my svg element, I want to enable the mouse drag to let use move it.

I have a single  elemen inside my svg where I want to prevent the drag because it has a click event and when the user clicks on it sometimes it drag the svg element.
The requested behavior is to drag as standard except when the mouse is down on this element.
I already try with event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault() but seems that svg-pan-zoom plugin has its own event management.

How can I prevent the mouse drag?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can [have 2 layers](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/layers.html) (if you don't need to pan/zoom that element).
2. Or you can still keep all elements zoomed but only [some of them listening for events](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom#listening-for-panzoom-events-on-a-child-svg-element). Just place everything you want to listen for events in one SVG Group element `<g>` and set it to listen for events.
3. Last solution would be to [override default events](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom#custom-events-support) for click/drag and write your own handlers.

I would recommend option 1 if you don't need your element to be zoomed, or option 2 otherwise.

Comment: I get my SVG it from a webservice, in this case I add my new element, I want to drag/zoom this element with the others. The 2nd would be ok, but I need to listen to all element except one, not just someone, so I would need a least a background element...
I solved with the 3rd solution and a little hack of original source because the publicInstance doesn't cointain handleMouseDown() and I need to intercept it.

Comment: You still could go with 2nd solution as you can have 2 root elements. Element 1 would be your element you don't want to listen for. Element 2 would be a group and would contain all the other elements (and you would listen for this element).

Comment: Do I need a background element for the second root element for this solution?

Comment: SVG doesn't require you to have a background element (I don't even know if such a thing exists). So no, you don't need a background element. 
Or maybe you do. I have no idea what's your specific case.